# Merge [package-managers] and [package-management]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I do not see why these should be distinct tags. I would also prefer for [package-management](/questions/tagged/package-management) to be the master tag, with [package-managers](/questions/tagged/package-managers) being its synonym.